# PHP decord base64 to jpg file

Tags: php, base64

I converted the image to base64 on Android and sent it to the server.

And in PHP, I tried to decode it into a jpg file.

But it was converted to png file.

Here is my PHP cord. Is there a problem with this?

```
<?php
  $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
  // Get file name posted from Android App
  $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
  // Decode Image
  $binary=base64_decode($base);
  header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
  $file = fopen('/home/jinwoo/Pictures/Logo/'.$filename, 'wb');
  // Create File
  fwrite($file, $binary);
  fclose($file);
  echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
?>
```

※ I have already confirmed that the image I sent was a jpg file.

Comment: Have you tried copying the image to a machine and running base64 in a known-good environment (e.g. copy image to linux machine, base64 image.jpg > image.base64 && base64 -d image.base64 > image2.jpg && diff andoird.base64 image.base64) to confirm the conversion on the Android device is as you expect? Have you confirmed that the image is an actual jpg, and not just a png with a jpg suffix (on *nix you can confirm by running file image.jpg)?

Comment: Why are you calling header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); if you're only printing text?

Comment: what is the value of $_REQUEST['filename']? I would be willing to bet that the filename has the .png extension, and so that would probably be coming from your app. Also, please (I will beg and plead) do not use $_REQUEST. Use either $_GET or $_POST or you will find yourself having all sorts of weird problems.

Comment: I am using Linux as a server. And even if the extension is jpg, is it not jpg?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on what your app sends to the server. I do not know what that is and you will need to find this out. You can do this by echoing out the variable or by writing it to a file, but I would guess that this would be where you will find your .png